# HTML/XML parser that executes bash functions and passes text as argument

Tags: bash, function, xml-parsing, tags, html-parsing

I need a program (bash, perl, ruby,it doesn't really matter) that parses html/xml and executes functions for tags and passes text between the tags as an argument.

## Example:

### Script:

```
#!/bin/????
. /path/to/parser
title()
{
cowsay $1
}
exit
```

### file.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body>
This is only a test.
<br/>
I hope it works!
</body>
</html>
```

### Usage:

```
./script file.html
```

### Result:

```
 _______________ 
< Hello, World! >
 --------------- 
      \   ^__^
       \  (oo)\_______
          (__)\       )\/\
              ||----w |
              ||     ||
```

## My Tries:

- A bash script that reads through the file one character at a time. Code not good enough to show here. :(
- Working on a solution using Ruby and libxml - no luck yet. :(

Comment: Good problem definition, but this borders on a request for free programming. Please update your question to show what you have tried. Good luck.

Comment: This question is really big.  Break it down into the smaller pieces that are confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just print the title as cow?

You can use any command line xpath interpreter that opens html for that:

My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html)

```
  xidel file.html -e //title 2> /dev/null | cowsay
```

[Xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

```
  xmlstarlet sel --html -t -v //title file.html | cowsay
```

---

You could print all html tags with their value, separated \0 and then run them:

```
title (){
  cowsay $@
}

xidel file.html -e 'xquery version "1.0"; for $i in //* return concat(name($i), " ", $i, "&#x00;")' | while read  -d $'\0' i; do $i; done
```

It will probably do some bash splitting of the arguments. (e.g. removing " or ', change multiple spaces to a single one)

The xquery version "1.0"; is there, so it parses xml entities like &#x00; in the string (although I have heard x00 is not actually allowed in XQuery strings, good thing I do not have error checks for invalid inputs, yet)

And it is probably safer to use `//title | //whatothertagsyouwant` instead of `//*` or you will get some problems, if someone has `<rm>-Rf /*</rm>` in his html file.

Comment: No, I want it to loop thought the file, and execute a bash function for every tag it encounters.

Comment: you can also print all values and process them

Comment: I edited your example so it checks if it is a function before executing.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chuckwagoncomputing/5880414